# Performance issue when calling isSpaceAscii

Tags: nim-lang

I tried to call the `isSpaceAscii` from the standard library but got worse performance than with my own proc.

Code to reproduce:

```
import strutils
import std/monotimes
import stats

template timeIt(tag: string, iter: untyped, body: untyped) =
  var st: RunningStat
  for i in countup(1, iter):
    let t0 = getMonoTime().ticks
    body
    let t1 = getMonoTime().ticks
    let d = t1 - t0
    st.push(d.float64)
  echo tag, ": ", st.min

proc isSpace(c: char): bool =
  result = c in Whitespace

when isMainModule:
  # check eqaulity
  for i in 1..255:
    let c = char(i)
    doAssert isSpace(c) == isSpaceAscii(c)

  timeIt "isSpaceAscii", 1000:
    for i in 1..255:
      let c = char(i)
      discard isSpaceAscii(c)

  timeIt "isSpace", 1000:
    for i in 1..255:
      let c = char(i)
      discard isSpace(c)
```

Benchmark results:

```sh
$ nim compile -d:release --verbosity:0 --hints:off --run test.nim
isSpaceAscii: 380.0
isSpace: 20.0
```

Compiler version:

```sh
$ nim -V
Nim Compiler Version 1.4.2 [Linux: amd64]
```

Why is `isSpace` faster than `isSpaceAscii`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Benchmarking is hard, because you're not always measuring what you think you're measuring.

The incredibly stark differences you're seeing are because the `isSpace` loop doesn't do anything, and is in the same compilation unit as the `isSpace` function, so the compiler can optimize it away
[as you can see on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/brPhaG)

if you instead compile with `-d:release -d:lto` the compiler will perform link-time optimization, and will optimize away both versions.

```
$ nim c -d:release -d:lto -r test.nim
isSpaceAscii: 16
isSpace: 16
```

We're just measuring the loop overhead.

To actually compare isSpaceAscii with isSpace, they need to do actual work as far as the compiler is concerned.

```py
import std/[strutils,monotimes,stats]

template timeIt(tag: string, iters: int, body: untyped) =
  var st: RunningStat
  when declared(warmup): #BUG
    for i in 1..iters:
      body
  for i in 1..iters:
    let t0 = getMonoTime().ticks
    body
    let t1 = getMonoTime().ticks
    st.push((t1-t0).float64)
  echo tag,": ", st.min

proc isSpace(c:char):bool = c in Whitespace

template badloop(procname: untyped) =
  for i in 1..255:
    let c = char(i)
    discard procname(c)

template goodloop(procname: untyped) =
  var x: int
  for i in 1..255:
    let c = char(i)
    if procname(c): inc x

when isMainModule:
  let nruns = 1000
  for i in 1..255:
    doAssert isSpace(i.char) == isSpaceAscii(i.char)

  timeit "isSpaceAscii, good",nruns:
    goodloop(isSpaceAscii)

  timeit "isSpace, good",nruns:
    goodloop(isSpace)

  timeit "isSpaceAscii, bad",nruns:
    badloop(isSpaceAscii)

  timeit "isSpace, bad",nruns:
    badloop(isSpace)
```

result:

```
$ nim -d:release -d:lto -r test.nim
isSpaceAscii, good: 439.0
isSpace, good: 382.0
isSpaceAscii, bad: 17.0
isSpace, bad: 17.0
```

Closer, but there still seems to be a discrepancy, what's that about?
T̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶p̶u̶ ̶h̶a̶s̶ ̶w̶a̶r̶m̶e̶d̶ ̶u̶p̶ ̶b̶y̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶t̶i̶m̶e̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶g̶e̶t̶s̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶e̶c̶o̶n̶d̶ ̶t̶e̶s̶t̶,̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶g̶o̶e̶s̶ ̶f̶a̶s̶t̶e̶r̶.̶  (**Edit** due to a bug `-d:warmup` didn't change the code, differences were due to the compiler making different optimization choices.)

Try again, t̶u̶r̶n̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶w̶a̶r̶m̶u̶p̶ ̶l̶o̶o̶p̶ we've added to `timeit`, and this time lets go all in for speed and use `-d:danger`

```
$ nim c -d:danger -d:lto -d:warmup -r test.nim
isSpaceAscii, good: 237.0
isSpace, good: 234.0
isSpaceAscii, bad: 15.0
isSpace, bad: 15.0
```

pretty much the same.

**Edit**  as if to highlight the inscrutibility of microbenchmarks, I was completely wrong about the warmup section.  I should have written `when defined(warmup)`, and because of that bug, my "warmup" code never actually ran.  Indeed, since we took the *fastest* time, the first few runs were sufficient warmup.

I've run several versions of the code since then, and the results vary too widely to draw any more conclusions, other than maybe:

- compilers' optimization choices are fickle
- Benchmarking is hard

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.